# Cannot run a .py which requires a gdal module in anaconda prompt nor in command prompt

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, gdal

I have created a new environment in anaconda, then installed the gdal module with

```
conda install -c conda-forge gdal
```

and I can see it by checking

```
conda list
```

Then I navigate to the folder with the .py file and enter [file name].py. The prompte returns:

```
  File "C:\Users\matdy\Documents\00_MSc\00_Master thesis\00_project\python\HDFtoGeoTiff.py", line 8, in <module>
    import gdal, os
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gdal'.
```

Python -V returns Python 3.9.7
gdal version is 3.3.2.

I created the new environment because it's not possible to install packages in my root anaconda environment doesn't work. It keeps on solving the environment.
I have also tried to execute the file with spyder with the same result
I have also tried to run the .py file via command prompt (with python 3.6.8). Previously I have manually downloaded the GDAL package file: GDAL-3.0.4-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl but the error is the same:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gdal'
```

Why can't anaconda nor the python 3.6 see the installed module? Is there any way to run this .py script?

Comment: Have you activated the conda environment with `conda activate` before running the `.py` script?

Comment: Yep, activated it with ```conda activate pygdal```

Comment: I have been through this and it is devishly difficult. Search on how to install Fiona and you will find hints how to install Gdal. Also this link may help: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: tried `from osgeo import gdal` ?

Comment: Finally managed to run the .py file in IDLE python 3.6

Comment: See this thread for more information about the deprecation: https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/3149

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the error occurs because of the default program for `.py` files
, look for `How to fix path for gdal .py scripts in Anaconda-Windows?` [here](https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2022-January/subject.html). There are some solutions there, like [this one](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/swig/python/gdal-utils/osgeo_utils/auxiliary/batch_creator.py). An alternative is to make the call explicitly, instead of calling `[file name].py` (that can invoke the default program for `.py` files), call `specific/python/install/[file name].py`, for example:

```py
import os
from pathlib import Path
import sys

def find_gdal_py(python_prog):
    # find the python executer calling this function
    # and search for the gdal program 
    python_prog = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(str(Path(sys.executable).parent), 
                                'Scripts', 
                                f'{python_prog}.py'))
    if not os.path.isfile(python_prog):
        print(f'*****Could not find {python_prog}.py')
        return False
    else:
        return python_prog

if __name__ == '__main__':
    python_prog = 'ogrmerge'
    gdal_py = find_gdal_py(python_prog)
    print(gdal_py)
```

That should print something like `C:\Users\your-user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\your-env\Scripts\ogrmerge.py`.